# Php function creates new array (data) from input or references to it?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have a general php question. I have an array of size lets say size of 3. And I pass it as an input to a function in an included file. So, does it copy the array (more memory) or actually make the function to references it ?

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
include(functions.php);    //doSomething() resides here
$result = doSomething($arr);
```

Comment: You can assume it will create a copy unless prepended with ampersand.

Comment: Copies unless you define the function arg as a reference `&$arg`. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array('a', 'b', 'c');
include(functions.php);    //doSomething() resides here
doSomething($result);
```

and define

```
function doSomething(&$result) {/* code */}
```

And not use more memory..